# How to handle nested groupings with possible null elements in one query

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concatenation

As you can see in [this sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7dee), I have three tables: `events`, `event_dates`, and `event_times`.

The original tables contain various other fields, which I omitted as they aren't relevant, I just need to have them in my final result, but I do no operation/sort/filtering/grouping on them.

An event has **1+** `event_dates` and an event_date has 0+ `event_times`.

From an object point of view, an event object has a list of event_date objects, which in turn can have a list of event_time objects.

My final goal is to obtain an array of event objects.

My plan is to design a query returning the ids of matching records and from these results fetch the records from their tables in 3 queries and assemble everything in code (this is necessary because of various data-transformations outside the scope of SQL).

**My problem is getting the first query right**

At the moment I have the following query

```
SELECT events.id,
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(event_dates.id SEPARATOR ','), ']') AS event_date_ids,
CONCAT('[', COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(event_times_per_event_date.event_time_ids SEPARATOR ','), '[]'), ']') AS event_time_ids
FROM events
INNER JOIN event_dates ON event_dates.event_id = events.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT date_id AS event_date_id, CONCAT('[', COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(event_times.id SEPARATOR ','), ''), ']') AS event_time_ids
  FROM event_dates
  LEFT JOIN event_times ON event_times.date_id = event_dates.id
  GROUP BY event_dates.id
) AS event_times_per_event_date ON event_times_per_event_date.event_date_id = event_dates.id
GROUP BY events.id
```

which fails in the following situation:

Given event *e* with three dates *d1*,*d2* and *d3*, where *d1* has two times (*t1,t2*), *d2* has zero times, *d3* has two times(*t3,t4*).
The result of the query would be:

```
event_id  |  event_date_ids  |  event_time_ids
1         |  [1,2,3]         |  [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

What I'd expect would be an empty array in event_time_ids, so that I could match the indices of the array in event_date_ids with the one for the array in event_time_ids:

```
event_id  |  event_date_ids  |  event_time_ids
1         |  [1,2,3]         |  [[1,2], [], [3,4]]
```

How can I obtain this?

P.S.: I deeply apologise if my question is chaotic or unclear and I'm ready to provide every other necessary information.

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks a lot to @Andriy M for spotting my mistake.

Moving on, I have to add to the equation `event_categories` where events have **1+** categories.

Adding a `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT` would break my current solution as empty arrays would be removed.
The solution is to make this query into a subquery, and join its results to a query fetching all other event data and grouping by `events.id`.
The event_time_ids would be duplicate for every event row, thus selecting any row for that column is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply [one small change](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7dee/3) to your query which is emphasised below:

```
SELECT events.id,
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(event_dates.id SEPARATOR ','), ']') AS event_date_ids,
CONCAT('[', COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(event_times_per_event_date.event_time_ids SEPARATOR ','), '[]'), ']') AS event_time_ids
FROM events
INNER JOIN event_dates ON event_dates.event_id = events.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT event_dates.id AS event_date_id, CONCAT('[', COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(event_times.id SEPARATOR ','), ''), ']') AS event_time_ids
  FROM event_dates
  LEFT JOIN event_times ON event_times.date_id = event_dates.id
  GROUP BY event_dates.id
) AS event_times_per_event_date ON event_times_per_event_date.event_date_id = event_dates.id
GROUP BY events.id;
```

In the derived table you are correctly grouping by `event_dates.id` but retrieving `event_times.date_id` instead. That is a mistake because when there is no match, it is null. And it is because one value is returned as null that the outer query omits the corresponding empty group. Replacing `event_times.date_id AS event_date_id` with `event_dates.id AS event_date_id` fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tested it yet, but reading your explanation I too understand where my mistake was. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Does this get column 2 correctly?  (For the moment, I am deliberately leaving off the brackets and commas.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_id FROM tbl ORDER BY date_id;
```

If so, let's use that resultset as the basis of what to the upper level in column 3.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT date_id FROM tbl ) AS all_dates
    JOIN ...  USING (date_id)
    ORDER BY date_id;
```

That query may be a subquery to another layer, whose purpose is to add the brackets and commas for column 3.

I'll leave it to you to fill in the details.  But I recommend you debug it until you have the right data; only then should you think about the brackets and commas.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the tip, I'll try that out later